# Сохранение данных в массив с помощью Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Я пытаюсь сделать кнопку, с помощью которой пользователь сможет сохранить некоторый объект в "Избранное". Структура у меня такая:

```
class FavoriteCoin: Object {
    var symbol = List<Coins>()
}

class Coins: Object {
    dynamic var coin = ""
}
```

Работать это должно так: пользователь нажимает кнопку и в "массив" типа String добавляется значение. На другом экране все эти значения используются. 
Как будет правильно реализовать такую задумку? Подскажите, пожалуйста, реализацию или место, где я смогу найти нужную мне информацию (у самого не вышло).

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#creating-objects, это офицальная докуменация realm для swift

Answer (score 1):

Открываем инстанс Реалма

```
let realm: Realm = try! Realm()
```

Создаем Обьет Сoins и Обьет FavoriteCoin
Добавляем обьект Сoins в масиив symbol
Добавляем FavoriteCoin прямиком в Базу

```
let bitCoins = Coins()
bitCoins.coin = "БИТКОИН" 
let favoriteCoins = FavoriteCoin() 
favoriteCoins.symbol.append(bitCoins)
try! self.realm.write { 
   self.realm.add(favoriteCoins)
}
```

Достаем FavoriteCoin из Базы

```
let favoriteCoins = realm.objects(FavoriteCoin.self)
if favoriteCoins.count > 0{
   let favoriteCoin = favoriteCoins.first!
}
```

И пользуемся на здоровье!

Лучше всего где-то хранить инстанс FavoriteCoin, в программе должен быть всего 1 экземляр этого класса.

Соответсвенно вы по нажтию на кнопку будете добавлять уже в созданную FavoriteCoin строки, не нужно создавать много обьектов этого типа.

В примере выше я описал простое создание, добавлении и как получить обьекты хранящиеся в БД. 
Советую перед началом работы ознакомиться с Документацией Реалма!
realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#creating-objects